# How to solve type error length is not defined

Tags: javascript

I use jquery 3.0.1. When my code is executed, I receive the error:

> TypeError: $(...).length is not a function

How can I solve it?

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $("#myList li").length();
    x=3;
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
        $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;
        $('#myList li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: The first step when a jQuery function doesn't seem to be working the way you expect (or at all) is to check [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) - which in this case would've told you there is no `.length()` function, but there is a `.length` property. As an aside, you should declare your variables with `var` (or `let` or `const` as appropriate).

Comment: I agree with nnnnnn. I actually received this error several hours ago, and it appears it shows up when there is a general problem with your code. As for your variables, you need to define them properly and there is no `.length()` function.

Answer (score 5):

it is `.length` not `.length()` that is the reason of the error change the line

`size_li = $("#myList li").length();`

to

`size_li = $("#myList li").length;`